# need app to map keyboard and mouse contols to wired xbox360 controller+chatpad

Tags: networking, keyboard, mouse

I have downloaded joysticks but it seems to just give diagnostics on the movements of the controls. Is there an app I can download to allow me to configure a wired xbox360 controller + chatpad to replace mouse and keyboard functions?  Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qjoypad (joysticks) is no longer supported, AntiMicro picks up where that left off.

In a terminal add the repo, update and install, with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ryochan7/antimicro 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install antimicro
```

Start from dash or run `antimicro` from a terminal.

[image]

Comment: As you are a rep 1 user, if this answer helped you, please accept with the check mark on the left, if not please explain why.

Comment: Mr. Kirby Thank you for helping I entered the command into the terminal, and experienced  some locked file problems.     gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
 any thoughts ?   thank you again

Comment: Try one command at a time, I will edit code in the question. If you get errors please provide the exact error

Comment: Update should fix your problem, don't forget `sudo` you must be root to install software.